# python shared Queue() in shared dict() in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I just learnt python multiprocessing. I want to make a model to simulate the process of sending and receiving messages in a networks. A directed graph describes the relation between two nodes and a dictionary describes the communication between two nodes. The data type of the value of this dictionary is queue. But I met some errors:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Manager

PoolGroup=[('R1','R2','R3'),('N1','N2','N3'),('E1','E2','E3')]
PoolElement=['R1','R2','R3','N1','N2','N3','E1','E2','E3']
graph={'R1':['N1','N2','N3'],
   'R2':['N1','N2','N3'],
   'R3':['N1','N2','N3'],
   'N1':['E1','E2','E3'],
   'N2':['E1','E2','E3'],
   'N3':['E1','E2','E3'],
   'E1':[],
   'E2':[],
   'E3':[]}

def addSigal(target,information):
    AllQueue[target].put(information)
    print("Succeed in sending msg to "+target)
    print(target+' now has ',AllQueue[target].qsize(),' signals')


def pool1function(name,information):
    targetlist=list(graph[name])
    print(name+" send information to "+str(targetlist))            
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool1:
        pool1.map(addSigal,targetlist,[information]*3)


if __name__=='__main__':
    m=Manager()
    AllQueue=m.dict()
    AllQueue.update({PE:m.Queue() for PE in PoolElement})
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:       
        pool.map(pool1function,PoolGroup[0],[1,2,3])
```

Unfortunately, the result just showed:

```
R1 send information to ['N1', 'N2', 'N3']
R2 send information to ['N1', 'N2', 'N3']
R3 send information to ['N1', 'N2', 'N3']
```

it means the information is not sent to the corresponding node. So I checked AllQueue and found something strange: when I print AllQueue['R1'], it showed:

```
RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unserializable message: ('#RETURN', <queue.Queue object at 0x10edd8dd8>)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also failed to put or get element from AllQueue['R1'], what's the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure that `AllQueue` is defined. Also please edit your question to remove redundant elements: are all the imports needed?

Comment: I tried to put the definition of AllQueue out of main, or make it global variable, the result was the same...

Comment: It seems that AllQueue goes out of scope when you use `ProcessPoolExecutor` or `multiprocessing.Pool`. You will need to pass `AllQueue` as a parameter through the `map` calls.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of passing the dictionary to a task:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Manager


def addSigal(target, information, q):
    print(target,information,q)
    q[target]=(information)
    print("Succeed in sending msg to "+target)
    print(target+' now has ',q[target])


if __name__=='__main__':
    m = Manager()
    AllQueue = m.dict()
    AllQueue.update({'A':0,'B':1})
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        pool.map(addSigal,'AB', [1, 2],[AllQueue,AllQueue])
    print(AllQueue)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. This works for one-to-one, but how about all-to-one? the one receives a sequence of number rather than one number, the value of dictionary is just one number, I'm afraid it's not enough...

Comment: Well, I think its down to you to work on this. I've shown that the principal problem is that different processes have their own copies of variables and the work-around is to send anything global through as parameters. You just need to keep going with this.